# All positive integer points up to a certain distance from a hyperplane

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, algorithm, intersection

I have the hyperplane $\sum_{i=1}^{d} x_i c_i = z$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, defined by the vector of postivive numerical coefficients $c_i \in \mathbb{R}, c_i > 0$, and the value $z > 0$.
I need a function in Mathematica that can return all positive integer points $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}, n_i \ge 0$ that are at most a distance $\epsilon$ from the plane.

I tried treating the question as an integer programming problem;

```
LatticePlaneIntersectionInstance[
  coefficients_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), rhs_?NumericQ, 
  precision_?(NumericQ[#] && # > 0 &)] := Module[{sol = LinearProgramming[coefficients, {coefficients}, {rhs}, 0, 
     Integers];
   If[(Abs[coefficients.sol - rhs]/Sqrt[coefficients.coefficients])  < precision, sol, {}]
   ]
```

Which does work in some situations; it will return at most one point and only if the point is exactly incident with the plane:

```
LatticePlaneIntersectionInstance[{5.2, 6.8}, 5.2 + 2.0*6.8, 0.1]
```

returns `{1,2}`

but

```
LatticePlaneIntersectionInstance[{5.2, 6.8}, 5.2 + 2.001*6.8, 0.1]
```

returns `{}`.

This didn't seem to work so well which is why I've reformulated the problem  as the intersection of a plane with a lattice.

Can anyone provide a different solution which will find all of the points and also take into account the precision parameter properly?

------------------EDIT------------------
Solved by kglr. Here is his code written as a function:

```
LatticePlaneIntersection[
  coefficients_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && And @@ Thread[# > 0] &), 
  rhs_?(NumericQ[#] && # > 0 &), 
  precision_?(NumericQ[#] && # > 0 &)] := 
 Block[{nnn}, 
  With[{coords = nnn /@ Range[Length[coefficients]]}, 
   If[Length[#] > 0, coords /. #, {}] &@Solve[
     Evaluate@Append[
       Thread[coords >= 0], 
       Rationalize[Abs[coords.coefficients - rhs] <= precision]
       ],
     coords, Integers]
   ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coeffs = Rationalize[{5.2, 6.8}];
rhs = Rationalize[(5.2 + 2.0*6.8)];
tol = 3;

pnts = {a, b} /. Solve[Norm[{a, b}.coeffs - rhs] <= tol && 0 <= a && 0 <= b, {a, b}, 
   Integers]
```

> {{0, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {4, 0}}

```
Graphics[{Hyperplane[coeffs, rhs], PointSize[Large], Red, Point@pnts}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {-1, 5}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I have written it into a function and put it in my question.